# Java - iCal4j - set X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html

Tags: java, ical4j

Is there a way to set this `X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html` using iCal4j?

I need to set HTML content on the description of some events.

Answer (score 3):

```
XProperty p = new XProperty("X-ALT-DESC");
p.getParameters().add(new FmtType("text/html"));
p.setValue("<html></html>");
```